# Работа с изображениями на смартфонах

Tags: изображения, android, ios

В связи с тем, что разрешения экранов у всех разное. Как сделать так, чтоб на каждом устройстве изображение было на всю ширину экрана (отступы `10-20px`)?
Создавать для каждого разрешения отдельное изображение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум 4 основных изображения нужно будет создать. Но если учесть то, что экраны не пропорциональные, то возможно Вам придется создать больше. Либо изучить [9-patch](http://habrahabr.ru/post/113623/) - все сильно зависит от типа изображений.

Comment: Получается пользователь скачивает приложение с избыточными изображениями?

Comment: да. поэтому приложения и толстеют. И если в 2010 на nexus one вмещалось 40 программ без проблем, то в 2013, теже программы уже никак не вместить.

Но после того, как приложения на устройстве будет установлено, с apk будет извлечено только необходимое.

Comment: Но некоторые делают следующее - с приложением поставляют средненькую графику. А при старте пользователю предлагают - хочешь классную графику, можем скачать. И выкачивают с сайта графику нужного качества. Более того, если появится новое популярное устройство с нестандартным разрешением, то просто на сервер добавляем новую графику (в программе конечно нужно предусмотреть, что такое может произойти).

Answer (score 1):

```
В зависимости от ситуации возможны разные решения. Но если вы делаете собственный компонент, то не в ваших интересах держать зашитыми в компоненте множества изображений с различными разрешениями, единственным правильным решением является самостоятельное вычисление размера изображения. Весь процесс занимает несколько этапов:
1 - Определяем пропорции эталонного изображения (от качества этой картинки зависит всё). К примеру картинка размером 800*600, будет иметь следующие пропорции 1/0,75 (за главную сторону берём ширину).
2 - Определяем площадь которая доступна компоненту (например 600*550).
3 - Вычисляем новые размеры эталонного изображения для компонента- ширина - 600*1 = 600, высота - 600*0,75 = 450.
А затем меняем размер. Если это простая BitMap то - Bitmap btmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(_temp_down_shd, 600, 450, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле есть способ, как обойтись 2умя:

Разделим устройства на две группы:

1. Смартфоны и планшеты 7.* (соотношение экрана ~2.3/1)
2. Планшеты 10.1 (соотношение экрана ~1.2/1)

Заводим для каждой группы отдельные рисунки. Остается лишь растягивать изображения при необходимости. Искажение не сильное, я проверял.

Если же нужна супер графика, то тут вам придётся заводить целый парк копий картинок